# Dealing with VueJS Scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm dealing with a scope problem and i can't use the workaround `let that = this;` I want to change the variable `error`. Here you are a  [CODEPEN Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYaeqx)

**HTML**

```
<div id="app" class="container">   
    {{error}}
    <br>
    <button type="button" @click="change()">Change Variable Error</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',

    data:{
      error: "a",
      item: {
        foo: function(){
            alert('Change!');
          this.error = "Something went wrong!";
        }
    }
    },
    methods:{
        change(){
        this.item.foo();
      }
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not make `foo` a method instead of putting it in `data`?  Why do you think that is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: I'm using a plugin that has a function as a parameter, i need to use in that way =/

Comment: context issue, `this` inside foo function is not the Vue instance. uses arrow function or `this.item.foo.apply(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not vue issue but javascript "THIS" issue. You can get what you want with this code in methods.

```
change() {
    this.item.foo.bind(this)();
}
```

In function foo, there is `this.error`. But this `this` is not bound to vue instance's scope. So, you should bind it on this scope before you call.

And plus, I don't recommend you to mutate the state in data property. It could be anti-pattern.

Comment: Or `this.item.foo.call(this);`